# onYouTubePlayerReady is not firing when the page is loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have the following jQuery script that loads a page with ajax, and i want to display a video using the Youtube API when the page is loaded:

```
$("#games_slides").load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
            ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
            ytplayer.cueVideoById("ylLzyHk54Z0");
            ytplayer.playVideo();
    }

    function loadPlayer() {
            var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
            var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
            swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?" + "version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", "youtubePlayer", "480", "295", "9", null, null, params, atts);
    }

    loadPlayer();
});
```

The player is loaded, so the loadPlayer functions is working, but the onYouTubePlayerReady function is not firing. Any idea why?

Comment: Is this on a webserver or localhost?

Comment: yes, i know about this, its on a webserver:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `onYouTubePlayerReady` function needs to be in the `window` context (so that the ActionScript code can call it after it's loaded), and your definition of the function appears to have some local context.

Try

```
window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
  ytplayer.cueVideoById("ylLzyHk54Z0");
  ytplayer.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: This saved me after I wrapped all my code in a self-invoking anonymous function and couldn't work out what had happened to that event firing. Thanks so much.